# copyfile_state_get always showing 0

Tags: c++, macos

I've been trying to use Apple's COPYFILE library (written in C) for a program I'm making (written in C++). I've got most of it working, but I can't figure out how to get the byte count. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/copyfile.3.html):

> #### COPYFILE_STATE_COPIED
>
> Get the number of data bytes copied so far.  (Only valid for copyfile_state_get(); see below for more details about callbacks.)  The dst parameter is a pointer to off_t (type off_t * ).

The usage for copyfile_state_get() is as follows (from the same documentation):

```
copyfile_state_get(copyfile_state_t state, uint32_t flag, void * dst);
```

My current code for it looks something like this:

```
// Main function:
off_t* currentBytes = 0;
copyfile_state_t state = copyfile_state_alloc();
copyfile_flags_t flags = COPYFILE_RECURSIVE | COPYFILE_DATA;
copyfile(//SOURCE, //DESTINATION, state, flags);

// Somewhere in the callback function:
cout << copyfile_state_get(state, COPYFILE_STATE_COPIED, currentBytes);
```

The copying part works fine (files get copied), but all that gets outputted from the callback function is `0x0`. I've tried using a pointer to a pointer to a `off_t`, and that **does** give me an actual address(?), such as `0x10335ad5c8`, however I can't seem to go any further than that. I'm not super familiar with pointers and addresses, so maybe I'm missing something, but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You're close, but don't post "something like this".  Post an example that's *complete* and that you have *tested* and that shows your issue.  Show us how you're interpreting `currentBytes` after the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should use something like this to pass in the address of an `off_t` so that `copyfile_state_get(...)` can fill in the value.

Also as the doc states;

```
All of the other functions return 0 on success, and less than 0 on error.
```

You probably want to print currentBytes not the return value.

```
off_t currentBytes = 0; // Space for an actual off_t
...
// Somewhere in the callback function
copyfile_state_get(state, COPYFILE_STATE_COPIED, &currentBytes);
cout << currentBytes;
```

Comment: Ah perfect. I don't why I didn't try this before, but it works! Thank you